# DataError: No numeric types to aggregate when using resampling in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

I have a list of dictionaries with values that I convert to a dataframe in pandas. I also convert the date-information (here measured in ms) to datetime and set a new index. The values are recorded every 5 seconds. When I want to resample them to 1 Minute I get the error message "DataError: No numeric types to aggregate" and I do not understand why. Here you see my code:

```
import pandas as pd

#convert list of dictionaries into a dataframe
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data)

#convert the date-information (here measured in ms) to datetime
dataframe['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dataframe['timestamp'], unit='ms')

#rearrange the columns
dataframe = dataframe.reindex(['timestamp','value'], axis=1)

#set the index to the column 'timestamp'
dataframe.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

#resample to a resolution of 1 minute
dataframe_minutes = dataframe.resample('1M').mean()
```

The problematic part is the last line `dataframe_minutes = dataframe.resample('1M').mean()`. Before that the dataframe looks like this:

[image: dataframe before resampling]

Do you have an idea, why I get this error because as far as I see it both columns have numeric values. I'd appreciate every comment.

Comment: What is `dataframe['value'].dtype`?

Comment: Thanks Chris for your answer. The datatype is object `dataframe['value'].dtype:  object`

Comment: Your value column is not numeric. You cannot aggregate non-numeric values.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Chris. But why is it not numeric. As far as I see it there are only numeric values in it?

Comment: They are probably strings: `'407.55'` Just convert them to floats: `dataframe['value'] = dataframe['value'].astype(float)`

Comment: Cool thank you for your answer Chris. It works. If you write your comment in an answer I'll accept and upvote it (only if you want). Independant of that I would like to thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. Good luck and happy coding.